# How To Get the Count of Ad-Hoc Query in Usergrid v2.1.0-rc1?

Tags: apache, usergrid

Is there a way to get search counting, similar like sql: `select count(*) where name='xxx'` in Usergrid 2.1.0-rc1?

I developed a cash app.  Users download offers in my app and I reward them their downloading.  I will need to know how many offers user download every day, every week and every month to manage their level.  So I am expecting a feature to let query the counting instead of always return the entities.

What is your recommendation way to do that in Usergrid 2.1.0-rc1?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, count isn't supported in queries. You could increment a counter every time the user downloads an offer, then do a time interval get on the counter

http://usergrid.apache.org/docs/counters-and-events/retrieving-counters.html